# Javascript alternative of jquery load()

Tags: javascript

Can someone please give me an example of pure javascript alternative to jquery load() ?
Or point me to the rite site with the example.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

This is not what I meant to ask.
I need to use Ajax to load a URL and insert returned HTML into a 'div'

I don't quite get the negative points. Someone at least care to explain what is wrong with my question? I search all over and could not find an example.

Comment: This is not what I asked

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. There are two `load` functions in jQuery, and I'd argue that the one I thought of is the more commonly used one.

Comment: @Felix Kling No problem, I amended my questing to make it clear. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make AJAX requests using pure JavaScript, you need to do something like this:

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Specify a function to handle the response.

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Process the AJAX response in here.
}

// Make the AJAX request
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://prajjwal.com/profile.json', true);
```

The first parameter to open is the type of request that you want to make. We make a 'GET' request in this case. The second argument is the url of the item that you're trying to retrieve. The third argument is a boolean that decides whether the request should be asynchronous or not. If the request is async, your function will not halt & wait for the request to finish.

It is also worth noting that this won't work in Internet Explorer 8 or below. To support those browsers, you need to use:

```
httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

To handle the response, your handler needs to have something like this:

```
function handleRequest() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
      yourdiv.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
    } else {
      console.log('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
  }
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleRequest;
```

httpRequest.readyState tells you how the request is progressing. A value of 4 means that the request is complete & ready to be processed.

Keep in mind that you cannot request resources on other domains with open().

Comment: This is not what I asked. Thanks.