# I have a problem whit load to javascript. Error: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an error using `.load`. It loads the information and everything, but in the browser console it throws the error:

> jquery-2.1.4.min.js: 4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the
>   main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the
>   end user's experience. For more help, check ....

I receive the encrypted arrangements, and in their corresponding files (`ControlDeEquipos.php` and `ControlDeMateriales.php`) I decrypt them to show them in dynamic tables. All good but as it is a responsive application, on a device with smaller screen it does not load the information and the error mentioned above comes out. My script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        arrayone = '<?php echo $arrayone;?>';

        arraytwo = '<?php echo $arraytwo; ?>';
        $('#table_arrayone').load('../tablas/ControlDeEquipos.php',{array: arrayone});
        $('#table_arraytwo').load('../tablas/ControlDeMateriales.php',{array: arraytwo});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that is a warning message from the jquery library.... are there script tags inside of the html content you are loading?

Answer (score 0):

If I weren’t trying to do this on my phone, I’d come up with a better answer, but this might help:

[Javascript alternative of jquery load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628753/javascript-alternative-of-jquery-load)

It’s not a problem with getting the data from the URL, it’s that the best way to do this kind of thing is *asynchronously*, so the web browser isn’t locked up until the response arrives, the way it happens with the old synchronous `load` method.